# Using Seaborn's relplot instead of Matplotlib's plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a line graph built using matplotlib with the following code:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 7))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
ax = plt.subplot(111)
df.plot(x='Date', y=['Burglary',
                    'Criminal Damage',
                    'Criminal Damage',
                    'Drugs',
                    'Fraud or Forgery',
                    'Robbery',
                    'Sexual Offences', 
                    'Theft and Handling',
                    'Violence Against The Person',
                    'Other Notifiable Offences'], ax=f.gca())
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

It works fine. df.head() looks like:

[image: first 4 rows of dataframe]

When I try to use relplot from Seaborn, I get the following error:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10) into shape (105)

Modified code is as follows:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 7))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
ax = plt.subplot(111)
sns.relplot(data=df, x='Date', y=['Burglary',
                    'Criminal Damage',
                    'Criminal Damage',
                    'Drugs',
                    'Fraud or Forgery',
                    'Robbery',
                    'Sexual Offences', 
                    'Theft and Handling',
                    'Violence Against The Person',
                    'Other Notifiable Offences'], ax=f.gca())
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Does the dataframe need to be in some different structure or am I missing something in the code? I want to use Seaborn so I can turn on or off the different categories so the graph is more readable when presenting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a long form dataframe for use with seaborn in this way.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Modified the data frame by `crime_plot = pd.melt(df, id_vars="Date", var_name="Crime", value_name="Count")`